# Android. Load Intent when clicking item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-recyclerview

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.recyclerviewShoes.apply {
            adapter = ShoeAdapter(ShoeRepository.getShoes())
            { shoeModel ->
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, ActivityProductDetail::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(ActivityProductDetail.CATEGORY, shoeModel.product_name)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        }
    }
}
```

My Adapter

```
class ShoeAdapter (
    private val shoeList: List<ShoeModel>,
    private val onClick: (ShoeModel) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoeViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ShoeViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemProductBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        return ShoeViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = shoeList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ShoeViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val shoe = shoeList[position]
        holder.bind(shoe)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onClick(shoe)
        }
    }
}

class ShoeViewHolder(
    private val binding: ItemProductBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(shoe: ShoeModel) {
        binding.apply {
            textProductName.text = shoe.product_manufacturer
            textShoeName.text = shoe.product_name
            textPrice.text = shoe.product_price
            imageShoe.setImageResource(shoe.image)
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the item in my RecyclerView, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `onBindViewHolder` function, replace this:

```kotlin
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    onClick(shoe)
}
```

with this:

```kotlin
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    onClick(shoe).invoke()
}
```